# How to ensure selected combobox item is in table? (Access VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access

My goal is to create a way to log why something was changed and who changed it.

I have 2 comboboxes that are populated by tables. I use VBA to define the RowSource when the form opens.

When the user clicks the send button, before anything is changed, I want to make sure that the comboboxes have 'valid' selections.

One combobox is a list of employees based on firstname & ' ' & lastname

the other is a list of pre-set reasons (i.e. "Incorrect Hours", Wrong Item #", etc.)

```
If Nz(Me.cmbReason, "") = "" Then
    fncMsgBox "Must select a reason from the dropdown for modifying a labor entry."
    GoTo Exit_btnSend_Click
Else
    If Not IsNull(DLookup("Reason", "tblEditReason", Me.cmbReason)) Then
        fncMsgBox "Must select a reason from the dropdown for modifying a labor entry."
        GoTo Exit_btnSend_Click
    End If
End If
   
If Nz(Me.cmbModBy, "") = "" Then
    fncMsgBox "Must enter who is modifying this labor entry."
    GoTo Exit_btnSend_Click
Else
    If IsNull(DLookup("FNAME & ' ' & LNAME", "EMP", Me.cmbModBy)) Then
        fncMsgBox Me.cmbModBy & " is not a valid name."
        GoTo Exit_btnSend_Click
    End If
End If
```

When I have "If not IsNull..." then it won't accept anything regardless of valid or invalid, if I remove the "IsNull" then I get a mismatch debug.

How do I ensure that what the user puts inside the combo box, is in fact in the table?

Comment: Maybe set combobox LimitToList property to Yes?

Comment: Surprisingly simple, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

June7 Comment - Maybe set combobox LimitToList property to Yes?

Resolved my problem.

LimitToList prevents anything not in the list from being accepted. When clicking on any other control in the form, it pops out the drop down until an item from the list is selected or it is left blank. Allowing the code I was using "If not IsNull(....." to do just what I was looking for!